# Using ManyToMany extra fields from template in Django

Tags: python, django

I'll use a slightly simplified version of the example from Djano's docs.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class MembershipInfo(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

So what I want to do is iterate through say, Group and Person in the template and get some of the info from the extra fields like so:

```
{% for group in group_list %}
    {% for person in group.person.all %}
        {{ person.membership_info.invite_reason }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't seem to work for me. I suppose I just can't find out the right way to access it.

Comment: What do you want to print? If a person is a member of 3 groups, which `invite_reason` do you expect? Or all of them?

Comment: Sorry, I missed out a somewhat important part, we first iterate over the group, then person. Oops. I've edited this.

Comment: And to be clear, I want the reason that corresponds to that group and artist.

Comment: Then you should do MembershipInfo.objects.order_by('group', 'person') in your view to change the sort order :)

Comment: So then what if I wanted to have them grouped by those things? As in, have a header for each group, then each artist within that group is printed along with the reason. Not sure that would work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
{% for person in person_list.all %}
    {% for membership_info in person.members_set.all }}
        {{ membership_info.invite_reason }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is not very efficient, but it's the only option I can think of that uses solely templates.

**Edit**. Another option is to select all MembershipInfo objects from the database, sort them by person and group and pass them to your template. That would need only one database query.

Comment: Efficient way is to `{% regroup %}` `MembershipInfo.objects.order_by('person', 'group')` by `person`